# Facebook App Review requirement

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have an application that does not have an interface. It's a simple crawler that would use the Graph API and from public pages, it would fetch website address of the company (if mentioned) that owns the page from **Additional contact info. section** This app is only for my internal usage as a developer.

Now, the problem is that when I try to access Graph API using the explorer, it throws an exception saying that the app needs to be reviewed before I can get the info.

Now, Facebook's app review asks for screencast. I've already submitted my app twice and it got rejected both the times.

This is really awkward since I'm looking for a very specific information from a PUBLIC page that doesn't even require a Login.

I don't know what to do.

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review/server-to-server-apps

Comment: Thank you so much for the reference URL @CBroe